# How to create google task api Task object back from json string

Tags: android

I am able to convert Google task object to json string, but how do i construct Task object from json string.

I can parse the json string manually but as Task class is a hashmap object, is there any direct and easy way to do this ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Gson might be what you're looking for - http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

It makes converting between Java objects and Json easy.